# Android: Black Screen appears on the screen when search operation is performed by android SearchView

Tags: java, android, searchview, mediastore, audio-player, android-music-player

I am making a music player application on android. My `Launcher Activity(MainActivity.java)` displays all the songs in a `Custom ListView`. My app was running perfectly and then I decided to add a `SearchView` widget in the `ToolBar`.
Now when I type a query in the `SearchView`, me `Searchable.java` activity opens up and after 2-3 sconds the whole screen turns black. The search results are shown for a brief time but the black screen stays there permanently.
If don't use the search option then the application shows no such behavior.

Comment: Please mention the reasons for the negative votes. It may prove to be helpful.

Comment: you should post your code where you getting problem. Without your code it is very difficult to detect where is problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app displaying black screen because you are doing search operations on your main thread , that's why your main thread hanging , check your log monitor you will get error like , too much work on main thread , for overcome this issue you need to perform your search operations on another thread or in background and update your view when search completed , you can use Asynctask for background task .

Comment: would using a fragment resolve the issue?

Comment: just put your search query for getting audio data list in asynctask it will handle automatically all the things   check this out for more details https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: So i was reading the link and I wanted to ask that since the operation to be performed is Searching, should I place the execute() method call inside onCreateOptionsMenu() method?